# C++ merge and sort 2 vectors

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, merge

Can I please have some help on this.
I have an array (vector of vectors), `InitTermStructure`.
I have a function that performs interpolation if the difference between successive first elements is not 0.5.
The Interpolated data is stored in the vector "Temp".

I am then attempting to merge the `InitTermStructure` and `Temp` vectors, sorted by the first elements.

All interpolation calculations work fine however the merge resizes the target vector, and adds zeros. I am assuming the dimensions are not merging properly. Is there something that can restrict this? It should be a 6x2 merged with a 2x2 forming an 8x2.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm> // merge function
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
using namespace std;

double Linear_Extrapolation(double X, double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2);

double Linear_Extrapolation(double X, double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2)
{
    return(y1 + ((X - x1) / (x2 - x1)) * (y2 - y1));
}

int main() {

const int Mat = 6;

  vector<vector<double>> InitTermStructure((Mat), vector<double>(2));

 InitTermStructure = {   
    { 0.5 , 0.05 },
    { 1.0 , 0.06 },
    { 1.5 , 0.07 },
    { 2.0 , 0.075 },
    { 3.0 , 0.085 },
    { 4.0 , 0.095}
  };

double dt = InitTermStructure[0][0];
int Maturities;
int IrregIntervalCount=0;
int count = 0;
double X, Y;

 for (int i = 1; i < Mat; i++)
 {
    if (InitTermStructure[i][0] - InitTermStructure[i-1][0] != dt)
    {
        IrregIntervalCount = IrregIntervalCount + 1;

    }
  }


 Maturities = IrregIntervalCount + Mat;

 vector<vector<double>> Temp((Mat), vector<double>(2));
 vector<vector<double>> TermStructure((Maturities), vector<double>(2));

 for (int i = 1; i < Mat; i++)
{
    if (InitTermStructure[i][0] - InitTermStructure[i-1][0] != dt)
    {
        X = InitTermStructure[i-1][0] + dt;
        count = count +1;

        Y = Linear_Extrapolation(X, InitTermStructure[i-1][0], InitTermStructure[i-1][1], InitTermStructure[i][0], InitTermStructure[i][1]);    
        Temp[count - 1][0] = X;
        Temp[count - 1][1] = Y;
    }
} 

  std::merge(InitTermStructure.begin(), InitTermStructure.end(), Temp.begin(), Temp.end(), std::back_insert_iterator<vector<vector<double>>>(TermStructure), [](const auto &a, const auto &b)   
                {
                    return a[0] < b[0];
                }
                );

 for (int i = 0; i <= Maturities*2.5; i++) // !!!! Should be (int i = 0; i <= Maturities; i++)   Maturities multiplied by 2.5 to show incorrect output.
  {
    cout << TermStructure[i][0] << "    " << TermStructure[i][1] << endl;
  } 
    return 0;
}
```

Output:
0   0
0   0
0   0
0   0
0   0
0   0
0   0
0   0
0.5 0.05
1   0.06
1.5 0.07
2   0.075
2.5 0.08
3   0.085
3.5 0.09
0   0
0   0
0   0
0   0
4   0.095

Comment: Is this C++11 or later, because otherwise I believe you must put a space between the `>>` sequence of `vector<vector>>`.

Comment: The error seems pretty clear - missing template argument before `(`, and the line's `std::back_insert_iterator(...` - no template argument.  See [the docs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_insert_iterator), and note the example.

Answer (score 2):

```
std::back_insert_iterator(TermStructure),
```

`std::back_insert_iterator` is a template, like `std::vector`.

Do you think that something like:

```
std::vector  a;
```

would compile? Of course not. You need to specify the template parameters. What is it? `std::vector<int>`, or `std::vector<char>`, etc...

After examining your code, I believe you want this to be:

```
std::back_insert_iterator<vector<vector<double>>>(TermStructure),
```

I haven't followed all the math here, so this may or may not be right, but at least it compiles, now.

P.S. This is redundant:

```
int Mat = 6;

vector<vector<double>> InitTermStructure((Mat), vector<double>(2));

InitTermStructure = {
    { 0.5 , 0.05 },
    { 1.0 , 0.06 },
    { 1.5 , 0.07 },
    { 2.0 , 0.075 },
    { 3.0 , 0.085 },
    { 4.0 , 0.095}
};
```

You're initializing a vector of a fixed size. Then you immediately replace the vector's contents. It is perfectly sufficient to have just:

```
vector<vector<double>> InitTermStructure = {
    { 0.5 , 0.05 },
    { 1.0 , 0.06 },
    { 1.5 , 0.07 },
    { 2.0 , 0.075 },
    { 3.0 , 0.085 },
    { 4.0 , 0.095}
};
```

Ditto for the other initialization, too.

Comment: @Fitzy Well, then there's some bug with other parts of your code.

Comment: Your question was about a compilation error. But, you do have a runtime error here: "Temp[i][2] = Y;" That's a buffer overrun. You probably meant "Temp[i][1]". You should learn how to use a debugger.

Comment: D'OH!  yep. Once that is fixed it compiles. The only problem is the merge does not seem to have worked. The Vector "TermStructure" has all elements = 0.

Comment: Well, that's what a debugger is for. Good luck debugging your code, now that it compiles and runs.

Comment: The output should be 8x2 in size. The merge data is there in the target vector, however the target vector appears to have been increased in size. The First 8 rows (which is what "Maturity' equals, and one of the dimensions of the vector is supposed to be) is filled with 0. Then 7 of the expected data rows, followed by another 4 of 0, and finally the 8th data point.

Comment: I need to make sure the dimensions go, for example 6x2 + 2x2 -> 8x2

Comment: Its is resizing the target to 20x2 = 8*2 + 2*2